# Why is the following equation true? - Product Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am studying the charge of a capacitor, but I don't understand the following equivalence:

$$e^{t/RC} \frac{\mathrm{d} V_c(t) }{\mathrm{d} t} + \frac{1}{RC}e^{t/RC}V_c(t) =  \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} [e^{t/RC}V_c(t)]$$

Why is this true?

Comment: It's the product rule, $(fg)'=fg'+f'g$, with $f(t)=e^{t/RC}$ and $g(t)=V_c(t)$. (The chain rule plays a role too, in differentiating $e^{t/RC}$.)

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... once that applies to your particular problem and not to nearly every one of trillions of equations.  Also, your question is about *physics*, not *mathematics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the product rule for derivatives $$\frac{d}{dt}fg = g\frac{df}{dt}+f\frac{dg}{dt}$$

you can easily see that

$$\frac{d}{dt}[e^{t/RC}V_c(t)] = V_c(t)\color{red}{\frac{d(e^{t/RC})}{dt}}+e^{t/RC}\frac{dV_c(t)}{dt} = \frac{V_c(t)}{\color{red}{RC}}\color{red}{e^{t/RC}}+e^{t/RC}\frac{dV_c(t)}{dt}$$

where i have highlighted in red the derivative of the exponential